# Как .NET выбирает версию SqlCLR?

Tags: .net, sqlclr

В приложении я работаю с типами `DbGeometry` соответственно использую библиотеку `SqlServerSpatial130.dll`.
На компьютере установлены `SqlCLRType 2008-2016`. Т.е. в папках `system32` и `SysWOW64` имею библиотеки:

```
SqlServeSpatial.dll
SqlServeSpatial110.dll
SqlServeSpatial130.dll
```

Запускаю приложение и через `Process Monitor` вижу что приложение обращается к более старой версии библиотеки:

```
15:11:38,5893796    MyCoolApp.exe   10200   CreateFileMapping   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SqlServerSpatial110.dll FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS   SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection:
```

Собственно вопрос - почему так происходит? Почему не вытягивается `SqlServerSpatial130.dll`?

**UPDATE**

И еще уточнение, что бы загрузить библиотеки я использую метод `LoadNativeAssembly` так же как в этом ответе https://stackoverflow.com/a/40880753/1382234 
Посему интересует, почему запросы не идут к библиотекам которые я загрузил, а отправляются в `system32`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа с DbGeometry идет через `SqlTypesAssembly`, который выбирается из списка, захардкоженного в сборке `System.Data.Entity`:

```
internal sealed class SqlTypesAssembly
{
    private static readonly System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> preferredSqlTypesAssemblies = new List<string>()
        {
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91",
        }.AsReadOnly();
```

---

Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, в свою очередь, в нативных классах-хелперах ссылается на `SqlServeSpatial110.dll`:

```
[SecurityCritical(SecurityCriticalScope.Everything)]
[SecurityTreatAsSafe]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 1)]
internal struct GLNativeMethods
{
    private const string GlLibraryName = "SqlServerSpatial110.dll";
    private const int IntersectionPatternMatrixLength = 9;

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [DllImport("SqlServerSpatial110.dll")]
    private static extern GL_HResult Combine(GLNativeMethods.CombineMode combineMode, [In] GeoMarshalData g1, [In] GeoMarshalData g2, [In, Out] GeoDataPinningAllocator resultAllocator); 
    ...
```

Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 13-й версии (и, соответственно, новый `SqlServerSpatial130`) скорее всего вытянет, если вы пропишете assembly binding для него в app.config, перенаправив все версии на 13.0.0.0.

Comment: я как понимаю это что то как из этого ответа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868326/unable-to-load-dll-sqlserverspatial-dll/48534294#48534294 . Как в таком случае узнать значение поля `publicKeyToken` и `oldVersion и newVersion`?

Comment: @МаксКливер нет, это не из ответа по ссылке, это просто по результатам ковыряния рефлектором сборки System.Data.Entity. Пропишите oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0". Вопрос, скорее, в том, зачем вам именно 13-я версия (или последняя, 15-я). Версии переписываются в двух случаях - (1) каких-то зависимостей для старой версии нет, а для новой - есть. (2) вы косвенно сослались на две разных версии сборки. например, на 11-ю через System.Data.Entity и на 15-ю напрямую - и вам надо убрать неоднозначность ссылки.

Comment: У вас же просто подгружается не последняя нативная сборка, если нет никаких проблем - то не стоит ничего прописывать.

Comment: @МаксКливер UPD к вопросу стоит задать отдельным вопросом :)

Comment: Благодарствую за подробное пояснение! Я не могу сказать чем вызвана необходимость использования новой версии библиотеки. Ну видимо есть какая-то причина.